# PACT Provider verification : Expected an Array but got a Hash

Tags: javascript, arrays, provider, pact

At consumer level test is :

```
describe('Listing first level taxonomies', () => {
    before(() => {
        return provider.addInteraction({
            given: 'GET call for first level taxonomies',
            uponReceiving: 'Get object for listing first level 
                            taxonomies',
            withRequest: {
                method: 'GET',
                path: '/api/taxonomies/8061159/taxons?deleted=false',
            },
            willRespondWith: {
                status: 200,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: firstChild
            }
        });
    });


const firstChild = eachLike({
'name': like('Geo'),
'taxons': [
    eachLike({
        'id': like(115590),
        'name': like('Africa'),
        'hasChildren':like (false)
    })
  ]
});
```

When i verify at provider level , I am getting the error as:
    Expected an Array but got a Hash 
    ({"name"=>"Demo Taxonomy", "taxons"=> 
    [{"id"=>8145188, "name"=>"manojtaxon", 
     "childCategoryName"=>"hello", 
     "hasChildren"=>true}
    Full error is present at : 
    https://pastebin.com/XvB17SXY

Please help me in resolving the issue 
What i think is array size is more at provider level thats why it is 
failing  .Though i have added like and eachLike ( Still it has not 
    resolved it ) .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your matcher is incorrect:

It should be like this:

```
const firstChild = like({
  'name': 'Geo',
  'taxons': eachLike({
          'id': 115590,
          'name': 'Africa',
          'hasChildren': false
      })
  });
```

Note the removal of `[` and `]`.

Also, you can avoid the `like` statements within an `eachLike` as it is implied by default. If you need to use a different matcher (e.g. a `term` then you can override that behaviour, but you seem to just be using `like` here).

Comment: Thanks for the response .It worked like this : 'name': like('Geo'),
    'taxons': eachLike({
        'id': 115590,
        'name': 'Africa',
        'hasChildren': false
    })

}
But if i want to add more elements on taxons like taxon[0],taxon[1] how do i that ?       I did like this firstChild = {
    'name': like('Geo'),
    'taxons': eachLike({
        'id': 115590,
        'name': 'Africa',
        'hasChildren': false
    },{
        'id': 115578,
        'name': 'Asia',
        'childCategoryName': 'Country',
        'hasChildren': true
    })    but it fails

Comment: It's saying it's expecting an array but got a hash. If the provider is returning a single object with `taxons` as an array, change the first `eachLike` to just a `like`